# Java Reflection example

Tags: java

I am very new in Java, I am trying to test a Java Reflection example which I got from Stack Overflow itself.

```
 public static String dump(Object o, int callCount) {
    callCount++;
    StringBuffer tabs = new StringBuffer();
    for (int k = 0; k < callCount; k++) {
        tabs.append("\t");
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    Class oClass = o.getClass();
    if (oClass.isArray()) {
        buffer.append("\n");
        buffer.append(tabs.toString());
        buffer.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(o); i++) {
            if (i < 0) {
                buffer.append(",");
            }
            Object value = Array.get(o, i);
            if (value.getClass().isPrimitive()
                    || value.getClass() == java.lang.Long.class
                    || value.getClass() == java.lang.String.class
                    || value.getClass() == java.lang.Integer.class
                    || value.getClass() == java.lang.Boolean.class) {
                buffer.append(value);
            } else {
                buffer.append(dump(value, callCount));
            }
        }
        buffer.append(tabs.toString());
        buffer.append("]\n");
    } else {
        buffer.append("\n");
        buffer.append(tabs.toString());
        buffer.append("{\n");
        while (oClass != null) {
            Field[] fields = oClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                buffer.append(tabs.toString());
                fields[i].setAccessible(true);
                buffer.append(fields[i].getName());
                buffer.append("=");
                try {
                    Object value = fields[i].get(o);
                    if (value != null) {
                        if (value.getClass().isPrimitive()
                                || value.getClass() == java.lang.Long.class
                                || value.getClass() == java.lang.String.class
                                || value.getClass() == java.lang.Integer.class
                                || value.getClass() == java.lang.Boolean.class) {
                            buffer.append(value);
                        } else {
                            buffer.append(dump(value, callCount));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    buffer.append(e.getMessage());
                }
                buffer.append("\n");
            }
            oClass = oClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        buffer.append(tabs.toString());
        buffer.append("}\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

When I am trying to this I am getting error:

> No Class Found and No main function.

Comment: can you provide full stack of exception?

Comment: @elinamohanty asking bad question will always attract downvotes and closing. I love to help beginners, send me mail,check my profile. If you get too many downvotes or closing then you may be banned from posting questions in future

Comment: Check you inbox @SpringLearner

Comment: @SpringLearner: you may be doing the OP a disservice - learning how to ask clear questions that contain sufficient detail is an essential skill for a developer. We also do not want to acclimatise new posters here to the idea that Stack Overflow is merely a chat forum where one can advertise for free private help. The whole point of the site is to create useful Q&A from real problems so that other people benefit in the future.

Comment: @halfer I totally agree with you. I agree with your point *create useful Q&A from real problems so that other people benefit in the future.* but as you can see the questions do not fit for future users and if OP will post questions like this then there is a chance of getting blocked. As you can see most of the questions OP has asked arent good.

Comment: It's not such a bad question @SpringLearner. It needed a bit of tidying and trimming, and probably now only needs a bit more in the way of error logs and stack traces, and it will be on-topic (though it may be a duplicate). I am sure the OP will be along in due course to fix it up (and please encourage them to do so if you are in email contact).

Comment: @halfer sure I will do,thanks for guiding

Answer (score 2):

Create a class in java in which will contain a main function.

```
public class StackOverflowExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Here call the method dump, sample follows.
         dump(new Object(),1);
    }
}
```

Followed by the method.

```
public static String dump(Object o, int callCount)
```